# Binding a generic class to a specific interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, icomparable

I am trying to make a generic class. Is there a way to make a constraint so that only objects that implement `IComparable` can be passed into my generic. For example:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{

}

public class MyFooClass
{
}

public class MyComparableFooClass : IComparable
{
    public int Compare(MyComparableFooClass q) 
    { 
        return 0;
    }
}

public class MyMainClass()
{
    private MyClass<int> _myIntClass; // This is okay since int implements IComparable
    private MyClass<MyComparableFooClass> _myComparableFooClass // This should be okay too since int implements IComparable
    private MyClass<MyFooClass> _myFooClass; // This should get a compile error since MyFooClass doesn't implement IComparable
}
```

Hopefully my example is clear. I just want `MyClass<T>` to allow objects that implement `IComparable`. I understand that the `where` constraint only works with classes, if I'm not mistaken. Is this possible or can someone offer a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)'s work with interfaces too. From the documentation

> where T : class The type argument must be a reference type, **including
>   any class, interface**, delegate, or array type.

So you can use the keyword `where` with `IComparable`:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : IComparable
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generic does work with *interface* also:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: IComparable
{
}
```